# REST and JSF: Library to use? How to solve it?

Tags: java, rest, richfaces, jsf-2

The problem:

When the user clicks on `www.example.com/myapp/myview?id=1` I need to display the item with id=1 which is in the database. To do that I need to execute bean methods. (Ideally the user would have to login first if not in cookies and then redirect but that's another problem).

I'm using **Richfaces 3.3.3** with **JSF 2.0** (So VDL is deactivated and Facelets have to be used yet) so it's incompatible with PrettyFaces (they use the built in Facelets into JSF2).

RestFaces does not have JSF2.0 Version and seems outdated (last version is from June 2008).

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/) it is used in 
[JbossSeam](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/RESTfulApplicationsWithSeam) which also integrates JSF with Rich- and Icefaces,Rest and much more.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/ if that helps ... or else try some magic with preRenderView event in jsf2

Comment: Prettyfaces is not compatible, as I said :P.